# CodeIgniter File Upload Class - Initialize different config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I've been Googling this for a bit, can't seem to find an answer.

From what I understand, this code: `$this->upload->initialize()` initializes the CI file upload class using the `upload.php` config file. What I want to do is use a different file.

I tried `$this->upload->initialize('upload_other')`, but that doesn't seem to work. I know you can just set a `$config` array in the controller, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Is this possible? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not Initialize / override configurations like that.

You can initialize by

```
$this->config->load('upload');
-- Some code Here -- 

$this->config->load('upload_other');
-- Some code Here --
```

OR you can do it by array as follows.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

// Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the class:
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

If you want to have anouther upload at same time you can change your config array.

```
$config2['upload_path'] = './uploads/small/';
$config2['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config2['max_size'] = '100';
$config2['max_width'] = '100';
$config2['max_height'] = '100';

$this->load->library('upload', $config2);

// Alternately you can set
$this->upload->initialize($config2);
```

---

**UPDATE**

you can specify your general data in config file. say

```
config['width'] = '100';

config['width2'] = '100';
```

Now use in your controller like

```
config['width'] = $this->config->item('width');

config2['width'] = $this->config->item('width2');
```

this way you can reuse same settings.

Comment: so, this is not possible at all? that sucks, having to put a config array on the controller itself. What if I wanted to use the same configurations on a different form? Do I have to declare this config array again?

Comment: seems there's really no real answer to my question out there. I appreciate the help folks. Marking this as the answer till someone figures out a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to avoid the use of a config-array? The other way is to create the upload.php-config file. If you want to use diferent configurations accross different controllers, you can always create and load a complete custom config-file: [Codeigniter userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) Here you can create multiple variables with differen upload-config arrays.

You can load this config-file in every controller and use these configurations by using the initialize method.

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work. `$this->load->config($config)` returns a boolean value, which I cannot use in `$this->upload->initialize()`. the only way for that to work is to load the config file and fetch each item one by one, which is basically the same as declaring the `$config` array in the controller.

Comment: You can just store an array in the config value:
`$config['upload_settings_1'] = array('upload_path' => './uploads/', 'allowed_types' => 'jpeg|', ).....`